# How to pass java script variables into json format

Tags: javascript, json, variables

i want to pass variable values into json below is what i am trying.

In javascript i am getting values like this:

```
var f_name= document.getElementById("firstname").value;
var phone_number= document.getElementById("number").value;
```

And then in JSON  i want to pass these values:

```
"Site": {
   "Name": "+f_name+", 
   "Phone": "+phone_number+"
 }
```

its not working. What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 3):

Create an object, then stringify it as JSON

```
var f_name       = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
var phone_number = document.getElementById("number").value;

var obj = {
    Name  : f_name,
    Phone : phone_number
}

var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Chances are however that you haven't [understood the difference between an object and a JSON string](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/), and that you don't really want JSON at all.